# Is there a newtonian limit approximation for gravitational time dilation?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

The [gravitational redshift equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_redshift) (for a spherically symmetric gravitational field) is:
[image: {\displaystyle 1+z={\frac {\lambda {\infty }}{\lambda {\text{e}}}}=\left(1-{\frac {r{\text{S}}}{R{\text{e}}}}\right)^{-{\frac {1}{2}}}}]

Within the Newtonian limit, there is an approximation:

[image]

The [gravitational time dilation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation) (for a spherically symmetric gravitational field) is very similar:
[image]

So the question is, like the gravitational redshift equation, is there a newtonian limit approximation of the gravitational time dilation equation?

I'm not trying to solve anything, there is no problem.  This is just a question for the sake of knowledge.

Comment: The concept of time dilatation doesn't seem to be compatible with the principle of having just one absolute time. The Newtonian limit should be the limit of completely vanishing time dilatation. (If you don't want that, anything else should at least be called "quasi-Newtonian" to highlight the difference.)

Comment: Is gravitational redshift not directly correlated with gravitational time dilation, regardless of the magnitude of the gravitational forces?

Comment: The Newtonian limit is $r_s\ll r$ or $v_e\ll c$ or $\beta\ll 1$. Approximate the square root as the first two terms of its Taylor series.

Comment: If you want to put this in an answer I could mark it as correct.